# How to make linked page transition with swup.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

## How to animate page transition using Swup.js and "/" link attribute ?

Hello, I am using *Swup.js* for page transition animation for my website. However, I don't know why the "/" attribute for my links doesn't work.
The */subpage.html* attribute is used to animate the transition when clickedIt looks like "/" is not taken into account. In fact, the code is trying to reach the *subpage.html* but in the parent folder due to the "/", and not to animate the transition.

#### Problems

1. However, the animation works well, but not the transition: I am still on my *"index.html"* and not switched in my *subpage.html*.
2. In addition, when I open my *index.html* with a local live server from Visual Studio, the transition doesn't work and I get the error **"Cannot GET /subpage.html"**.

#### What I've tried

1. Follows the help from https://swup.js.org/common-issues, and https://github.com/swup/swup/issues/30, but none worked.
2. Changed the options parameters for *Swup()* in my javascript. I added `let options = {LINK_SELECTOR: 'a',debugMode: true,};` to `const swup = new Swup(options);` to get rid of the "/" attribute for transition (just to know if I can get it work), but I did not succeed: animation AND trnasition did not appeared...

#### My code

For this example, the button is linked to *index.html* so there is no *subpage.html*, but the transition don't work either.
The animation *transition-fade* works, but then the page *index.html* is no longer shown.

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    background: rgb(255,0,0);
    padding: .5em;
}
nav a{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

main{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5em auto;
}
main a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: .8em;
    margin-top: 2em;
}


/* Swup Animation */
.transition-fade {
    transition: 0.4s;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
html.is-animating .transition-fade {
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UAV-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>SWUPE test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">company</a>
        </nav>
        <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
            <h1>Home page here</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda quasi reprehenderit non corrupti quae quis facilis natus veniam quas quibusdam? Provident voluptates nemo excepturi corporis saepe obcaecati sapiente, quas culpa!</p>
            <a href="/index.html">Go to other page</a>
        
        </main>
    </div>

    <script>
    const swup = new Swup();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a class on the link like this.

```
<a href="/index.html" class="transition-fade">Go to other page</a>
```

Also it's a good practice that all your script tags go just above closing body tags and not head.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running your website without a server (with file protocol, eg. `file://` in the URL), where swup won't work as it's unable to make requests.

Let's assume we're at the URL `https://example.com/subpage1/`. The following links will trigger different locations:

- `https://example.com/index.html` - goes to that exact URL.
- `/subpage2/` - goes to the same site and the exact path - `https://example.com/subpage2/`.
- `subpage/` - goes to the same site and path relative to the current - `https://example.com/subpage1/subpage2/`